# How to included 2 shared mailbox in the same Power Automate Flow?

Tags: power-automate, shared, power-automate-custom-connector

I builded a flow on Power Automate Online where I take some datas from Invoices. But my flow run with 1 Shared MailBox and I need to imput more 1 Shared MailBox. How I Do this?

Thanks,
Bruno Rimoldi

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBZsC.png)

I hope there is a way to put 2 shared email boxes within the same flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot - you will need a trigger per mailbox and therefore a flow per mailbox.

Two suggestions for you:

1. Set-up a forwarding rule from one mailbox to the other.
2. Have a flow per mailbox (ie two) and have each of these call a Child Flow where you can re-use the same logic. Child Flow can need to be created in a Solution - see [Create child flows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/create-child-flows)